# Telegram login widget in an Angular iframe error

Tags: angular, iframe, telegram-bot

i'm adding a telegram login support for my angular site like thi

```
export class TelegramLoginWidgetComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChild('script', {static: true}) script: ElementRef;

  convertToScript() {
    const element = this.script.nativeElement;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?5';
    script.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', environment.telegramBotName);
    script.setAttribute('data-size', 'large');
    // Callback function in global scope
    script.setAttribute('data-onauth', 'loginViaTelegram(user)');
    script.setAttribute('data-request-access', 'write');
    element.parentElement.replaceChild(script, element);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.convertToScript();
  }

}
```

the script loads perfectly, the problem is that the iframe that the script loads throws an error

`Refused to display 'https://oauth.telegram.org/embed/...' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors http://127.0.0.1".`

Answer (score 1):

When Telegram API build iframe with "Log in with Telegram" it makes a request
like

`https://oauth.telegram.org/embed/csssr_id_dev_bot?origin=http://127.0.0.1`

and add to response Header `Content-Security-Policy: http://127.0.0.1`.

Because you run your app on http://127.0.0.1:3000 (or some another dev port)
polices did not match (port matters) and the error occurred.

How to fix:

1) Login widget require non localhost domain and doesn't work on custom post, so `localhost:3000`or any another port is impossible to use. You should register your bot domain with BotFather to get that work (for example `my-app-dev.com`). See https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login#linking-your-domain-to-the-bot.

2) Add this domain to the /etc/hosts line

`127.0.0.1 my-app-dev.com`

3) Run app on port `80`, this require `sudo` or running with Docker and port mapping `80:3000` (open port 80 on host machine).

Comment: So is there any way to specify the port ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to specify the port and run my app on port `80`

1) bind a domain to tg bot, see https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login#linking-your-domain-to-the-bot, for example `my-app-dev.com`.

2) add to the /etc/hosts line `127.0.0.1  my-app-dev.com`.

3) Run app on port `80` (require sudo or running with Docker).

Comment: it looks like answer, but problem is that it doesn't help at all. sound like "you need to make it work"

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Danke