# Inline script isn't rendering

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";



export default function App(){
  return (
    <main className="text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 body-font">
       <div className="containers">
      <Helmet>
      <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?15" data-telegram-post="#####" data-width="100%" />
      </Helmet>
      </div>       
      </main>
  )
}
```

Complete beginner to react. Trying to render telegram widget inline script. Is there something I'm doing wrong because I cant seem to get any output. Would to be a good idea to process this on backend first ?

Comment: I'm seeing an x-frame-options error. This means Telegram is preventing you from loading the widget in an iFrame here, it's not a React issue. This post "may" be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649030/telegram-login-widget-in-an-angular-iframe-error

Comment: I tried running the code on codesandbox.io. Which should probably overcome the port issue but I get similar results.